# Monodroid, WP7 and WinForms in same Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xamarin.android

I am developing a cross platform application using Android(Monodroid), iPhone(MonoTouch), WP7 and Windows and would like to keep my code base as coherent as possible. The iPhone requires a Mac which is fine I can deal with that but Android allows development in Visual Studio which is great as I can manage three projects under the one solution.

Now adding an new android project to a new visual studio solution will allow me to deploy in the emulator just fine. Same goes with a new solution and new WP7 project and corresponding emulator.

The issue I have is that if I setup a new solution with a WP7 project first and then add an new android project to the solution I cannot launch the android project as it always defaults to the WP7 emulator even when I set the android project to active project.

From what I can gather I think VS2010 will allow an emulator for the solution but will not allow an emulator per project within the solution. Has anyone come across this? Is there a work around maybe via command line? One workaround would be to have two visual studios open at the same time but I am trying to avoid that if possible.

**Source of the problem has been identified and solved**

Within the same solution don't give different project type executables the same name as this causes Visual studio a problem when determining which emulator to select. I changed the names for my launching apps for each project within the solution and everything works fine.

Original:

1. Solution \ Android \ MyProject
2. Solution \ WinPhone \ MyProject

Fixed:

1. Solution \ Android \ MyProject1
2. Solution \ WinPhone \ MyProject2

Answer (score 0):

This might be controlled via the "Deploy" setting.  Try disabling Deploy for the WP7 project in your solution configuration manager.

Comment: Thanks. Nice suggestion. I checked the solution properties and the WP7 project allows me to check/uncheck the project but the android project unfortunately is grayed out. I will investigate this further.